# i am getting array[array{json}] in angular

Tags: angular

This is my angular code

```
  constructor(public channelservice: ChannelService) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.channelservice.getAll().subscribe((data: Channeldata[])=>{
      this.channels =data;
      console.log(this.channels);
    })  
  }
```

This is i am getting in console

[image]

I cannot print it on template like this

```
<div *ngFor="let channel of channels| keyvalue">
```

{{ channel.channelid}}

Comment: You need to iterate another one loop to get the value. `<div *ngFor="let pChannel of channels| keyvalue"> <div *ngFor="let channel of pChannel"> {{channel.channelId}}</div></div>`

Comment: And you don't need the `keyvalue` pipe

Comment: @mkHun  

Get this error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: You should delete that image and roll those credentials as soon as possible

Comment: @Asad My mistake, as per cy3er said please remove the keyvalue pipe. Because *NgFor only works for the Array not an object. But keyvalue pipe will provide the result as object that is the reason you are getting error like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the data like Array of Array of Object, So you need to make another one loop to access the inner level values.

```
<div *ngFor="let pChannel of channels">
 <div *ngFor="let channel of pChannel"> {{channel.channelId}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You got a typo. Change channel.channelid to channel.channelId

Comment: That answer should be a comment